# Forge/ Bim360: How can we create Issue with custom attributes mapped with issue type using BIM360 API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In BIM360 Issue Type, we can add the custom attributes. So, our requirement is when we create an issue, we also want to add the custom attributes which are mapped to the issue type. Is there any API available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this official tutorial to "Retrieve Issue Custom Attributes Mapped to an Issue Type":

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issues/retrieve-custom-attr-issues/

While creating the issue, you need to specify these two attributes to map issue type and sub-issue types, `ng_issue_type_id` and `ng_issue_subtype_id`

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issues/create-issues/#step-3-create-the-issue